# How to create an Elasticsearch index with firebase RTDB

Tags: json, elasticsearch, firebase-realtime-database

Elasticsearch seems to expect the json data to be an array but firebase real time database stores the data in a gigantic object which makes it impossible to create a search index. I'm trying to build an autocomplete. Not sure if I'm missing something here.